# How to insert code in monaco editor using Playwright?

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright, playwright-test

I'm new to *Playwright* and I am trying to test a feature containing monaco editor, and couldn't find anything related in *Playwright* docs and forums.

This is my test:

```
async ({ page }) => {
    const testPage= new TestPage(page);

    await testPage.navigateTo();
    //dosomething
    await page.waitForSelector(#monaco-editor-selector);
    //Paste a script in monaco editor
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Playwright has a closed [issue #14126](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14126) on this with a good answer, pasted below.

```
test('Should write content in Monaco Editor', async ({ page }) => {
  const monacoEditor = page.locator(".monaco-editor").nth(0);
  await monacoEditor.click();
  await page.keyboard.type('Hello world!');
})
```

If you have multiple Monaco Editors and want to access them by some it, you can wrap them in a `<div>` with a test ID. Unfortunately you can not set `data-testid` directly to the Monaco Editor component.

```html
<div data-testid="my-test-id">
  <MonacoEditor ... />
</div>
```

```
test('Should write content in Monaco Editor that is wrapped inside a div', async ({ page }) => {
  const monacoEditor = page.getByTestId('my-test-id').locator(".monaco-editor").nth(0);
  await monacoEditor.click();
  await page.keyboard.type('Hello world!');
})
```

Comment: There is a problem when text contains brackets, for example a function. Monaco automatically adds close bracket ("}") which leads to a double closing bracket.

Most reliable way is to simulate a paste event instead of "typing" a text.